# Turning data into horizontal bar graph with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to create a horizontal bar graph from my data.

The link to my data is [here.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-wFayNDYUjKXfJUu1Wk-cJF1ekIJG41E/view?usp=sharing)

The code that I am using

```
library(ggplot2)



ggplot(data=df , aes(x=fct_inorder(WorkSchedule),y=timing, fill=Value)) + geom_col()  + coord_flip()
```

The output of the plot:

[image]

How to change the `x-axis` to show time from `04:00 till 03:45 (24h)`

I tried `factor(Source)` but it does not work.

[image]

UPDATE@ How can I change the x axis of this graph?

Many tahnks

Comment: I can't dowload your sample data

Comment: @Bruno thank for your time a ggole drive link to data https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-wFayNDYUjKXfJUu1Wk-cJF1ekIJG41E/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the function `lvls_reorder()` from library **forçats**, you can specify the order of the levels of your variable.

library(tidyverse)   # forcats is included in tidyverse library

```
df <- df %>%
   mutate(Workschedule = lvls_reorder(Workschedule, c(3,2,4,5,1))
```

If you transform the variable `Source` as a factor, you can also determine the order you want.

Comment: @demarsylvsin thank you for your time uploaded again my datahow can I specify the order with forcats?

Comment: i edited my answer with an example. If 'Length ...' is the third level (according alphabetic order) and you want it to be the first, start order with 3.